# Servlet vs Webservices

Tags: web-services, rest, servlets, soap

Webservices like REST, SOAP which provides services which is made available for web application, as we know it can receives values as JSON, string, XML etc either by POST or GET and in the same way it can return data as JSON, string, XML etc.

The same thing can be done via servlet, as servlet can receive data as string, JSON etc either by POST or GET and in the same way it can return data as JSON, string, XML etc.

We need libraries based upon the web service we use, such as SOAP or REST, servlet libraries are almost in-built int it.

So whats the difference between Servlet and Web Services? Which one is more faster?

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this.

Comment: I did a lot research, built demo apps, trained others & wrote lengthy notes, if you starting from scratch see my github notes here, for a full overview: https://github.com/manoharreddyporeddy/my-programming-language-notes/blob/master/my-java/src/web-services/README.MD

Answer (score 22):

This is the kind of discussion that can lead to a lot of flame wars on semantics, but I would say web services are simply a method of communication utilizing standards to allow different technologies to be interoperable. Like an English-speaker translating between a French- and German-speaker.

Meanwhile, the way to implement web service endpoints (the places that serve responses to your requests) in a Java web server is with servlets. So servlets are simply a technology for implementing web service communication (in the JVM).

When you look at JAX-WS and JAX-RS, the frameworks that implement these standards are simply creating abstractions on top of Java's `HttpServlet` (typically) to make SOAP and REST web services easier to build by taking care of a lot of the low-level details.

Hope that helps.

Comment: why cant servlet be used for communication since it can receive params and generate say json.....then it can also do the same thing as webservice do....

Comment: You're exactly right. That was my point. Let me put it more simply. Web services (whether SOAP or REST) are a set of standards for interoperable communication, and servlets are Java's way of helping to implement those standards. If someone said to me, "Go build web services with Java," I would do it with servlets (or really a framework that uses servlets).

Comment: +1, You are absolutely right.... for webservices is it necessary that we should use servlet for implementation, according to my knowledge i don't know whether its right or not, webservices can have its own methods for implementation and executing business logic

Comment: I guess I'm not being clear. They're basically the same thing. You use servlets to implement web services in Java. Go use RESTEasy, Spring MVC, or Apache CXF to build your services. They are using servlets under the hood, but let the frameworks deal with that.

Comment: +1. One note. When using JAX-WS, you create a web service using ordinary Java classes, annotating them with [`@WebService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jws/WebService.html) (usually you annotate a Java interface, then provide an implementation), i.e. they are NOT servlets themselves . Although true, that when using some JAX-WS implementation/framework, like [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/), or [JAX-WS Reference Implementation](https://jax-ws.java.net/), there will be a ready-made servlet to accept the requests, that in turn will call (delegate to) your web service.

Comment: if a servlet does the following tasks: takes xml/json request -> process it and return xml/json response -> can it be called a Web service ?

Comment: No. A web service is an implementation of request/response. A servlet is a kind-of basic building block which permits one to create different implementations of request/response. Conceptually, they are different, even though the means to an end could be identical. Also, typically, we think of web service calls as stateless (i.e. typically won't be including cookies) communication between client and server. A web service can be stateful (not REST) and use cookies, but web service bread-and-butter is typically stateless.

Answer (score 0):

where are a lot of difference between servlets and web services, but the main is:
in the web development servlets is the front end object and work in the web container, Web services can have different roles: as backend or as middle layer object.